# Как добавить дочерний элемент ко всем элементам с определённым классом?

Tags: javascript, html

```
let p = document.getElementsByClassName('task_text');
let b = document.createElement('button');
for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].appendChild(b);
}
```

Пытался сделать так но не получается.

Comment: `нацепить блок всему классу` - сами-то поняли что спросили?

Comment: Имею ввиду всем элементам с таким классом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В js есть `querySelectorAll` - метод, который возвращает массив всех элементов, подходящих под фильтр.

```
let p = document.querySelectorAll('.task_text');
for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
}
```

Comment: Почему-то кнопка цепляется только к последнему элементу

Comment: @CaesarJulius исправил, вы пытались добавить одну и ту же кнопку ко в сем элементам

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь понял!

Comment: @T0xee.n17 а чем вас `getElementsByClassName` не устраивал? :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 да так привык к querySelector, что вообще забыл про его существование xD

Comment: @T0xee.n17 понимаю вас :) Но `getElementsByClassName` как я помню динамичный, в отличие от `querySelector`. P.S. Только что перепроверил, так оно и оказалось, `getElementsByClassName` возвращает живую коллекцию, а `querySelectorAll`, нет.

Comment: @ΝNL993 хмм, интересно, не знал про такую особенность. Спасибо)

Comment: @T0xee.n17 не за что :) Такая же штука с `getElementsByTagName`, он тоже возвращает живую коллекцию. (Просто к сведенью)